# What does "versus" mean in the context of a graph?

Tags: notation, graphing-functions, elementary-functions

Say you have a graph of say $y=mx+b$, with $x$ on the horizontal axis and $y$ on the vertical axis. You need to give the graph a title, would you say:

This is a graph of "$y$ versus $x$?"

or

This is a graph of "$x$ versus $y$?"

Is the independent variable always first like $independent$ versus $dependent$, when you say versus or, the other way around?

Tried general searching, and doing a CTRL+F for "versus" on graphing related Wikipedia pages but couldn't find anything on this, hopefully im not the only one who has been confused by this?

To clarify, the problem im stuck on because of this, and from other encounters with this terminology, the side of "versus" a variable is on, is related to which variable is the independent variable and which is the dependent variable. That is the relationship i am asking about. Not whether $y$ is a function of $x$ or vice versa.

Comment: In my experience that terminology isn't really used, so if no one else is confused by it, it's probably because of that.  Personally, I'd be inclined to say 'independent versus dependent', but don't really know why I'm inclined towards that.

Comment: I can honestly say i don't think i have heard the "versus" terminology used in math courses, but i hear it and see it used all the time in other sciences courses, chemistry, physics, etc. Ive wondered about it for so long but am finally stuck on something, where the interpretation is makes or breaks the answer. And i just cant tell at all from context, any hints to how the "versus" is being used...

Comment: Logically, I'd say "$x$ versus $y$" since you're seeing what $y$ results from a given $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In physics, this is usually used as dependent versus independent as in a velocity versus time or position versus time graphs. See [Motion graphs and derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_graphs_and_derivatives) as well as from [Line chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_chart) we have "The chart can then be referred to as a graph of 'Quantity one versus quantity two, plotting quantity one up the y-axis and quantity two along the x-axis.' "

---

Some other references - [Physics from University of Kentucky](http://www.pa.uky.edu/~phy211/Plotting.html), [the same question on English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/is-x-plotted-against-y-or-is-y-plotted-against-x), [Astrophysics from University of Chicago](http://astro.uchicago.edu/cara/outreach/resources/other/howtograph.html). Nothing that would be considered a primary source if you are doing a research paper but enough to support dependent versus independent.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but on the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_chart , the Structure section doesn't have any references, nor does the Example section below it. Something i guess more authoritative or definitive would be helpful?

Comment: I would agree with the rule "[dependent] versus [independent]." The word "versus" can mean "compared with," and it more frequently makes sense to compare a dependent value with its associated independent value, because well, the independent variable doesn't really "care" about the existence of the dependent variable, but the converse relationship is by definition.

Answer (score 3):

I have always interpreted "y vs. x" as y = f(x) with y the dependent variable and x as the independent variable and will continue to do in my mathematics and physics lectures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (as is often the case) come from Latin.  "versus" simply means against and is used in the sporting context as well.  We say that in some contest "Team A versus team B", meaning team A is against team B.  The graph is the same - one variable is plotted against (or versus) another.  From the same cognate root we also get the English "adversary".